# How to use 2 php handlers on one server?

Tags: php, apache, cgi, handler

I am new to apache, PHP on linux. I have a server with PHP handler set as "**CGI**" I mean in phpinfo page where it says "**SERVER API**".

Now I have to install new script on server and the script requires PHP handler as "**APACHE 2 HANDLER" i.e. DSO** if i am not wrong.

There are scripts/live sites already running on the server. I am worried as what if after I change my server PHP handler from **CGI to APACHE 2 HANDLER**, my previously installed sites will have any bad effect in the matter of permissions issue or some other errors.

I would like to know whether is this possible to use "CGI" and "APACHE 2 HANDLER" on single server ?
if yes then **how to** ?

thanks for your time, have a great day ahead

Comment: Not using CGI as all is usually a good idea. Its performance is really bad as it starts a process for every PHP page.